# Retornar fecha en español MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, mariadb

Tengo una duda al usar `date_format` en MySQL: quiero retornar los nombres de los días y meses en español, pero por defecto salen en inglés. Tengo claro que en un view no se puede usar `{set @@lc_time_names=es_ES}`, podría setearlo en el my.ini pero, ¿no hay alguna otra forma?

Estaba pensando en crear una tabla dentro de la base de datos y almacenar los nombres traducidos ahí, e invocarlos con una consulta. ¿Alguno conoce algún otro método?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) – dd/mm/yyyy

CONVERT(varchar(19), datecolumn, 103)
```

Aquí te explica el número dentro de la función convert

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Y en este link de StackOverFlow en inglés creo que te resolverá más dudas 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741750/change-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-sql

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que realmente necesitaba es dada una fecha por ejemplo 24-05-2017 obtener el nombre del dia en español (miercoles), actualmente la obtengo como wednesday, eso dentro de un CREATE VIEW que no me permite ejecutar la instruccion SET. Creo que la forma mejor es crear una tabla (0, lun, lunes) y asi sucesivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo resolví haciendo dos tablas, una con los nombres de los meses, y otra con los dias, nombre largo y corto (3 caracteres) en ambos casos, con sus traducciones. Pude resolverlo de esa manera en el VIEW.